# Run function based on .pathname

Tags: javascript, function, pathname

So I've got this code in my page: a very simple but working script to translate it to several languages.

```js
// preparing language file
var aLangKeys=new Array();
aLangKeys['en']=new Array();
aLangKeys['es']=new Array();
aLangKeys['fr']=new Array();
aLangKeys['cn']=new Array();

aLangKeys['en']['language']='english';
aLangKeys['es']['language']='espa&ntilde;ol';
aLangKeys['fr']['language']='français';
aLangKeys['cn']['language']='中文';

aLangKeys['en']['buy']='buy';
aLangKeys['es']['buy']='comprar';
aLangKeys['fr']['buy']='acheter';
aLangKeys['cn']['buy']='买';

$(document).ready(function() {

    // onclick behavior
    $('.language').click(function() {
        var lang = $(this).attr('id'); // obtain language id

        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'es') {
          $('.language').attr('id', 'fr');
        }

        else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'fr') {
          $('.language').attr('id', 'cn');
        }

        else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'cn') {
          $('.language').attr('id', 'en');
        }

        else if ($(this).attr('id') == 'en') {
          $('.language').attr('id', 'es');
        }

        // translate all translatable elements
        $('.translate').each(function(i){
          $(this).html(aLangKeys[lang][ $(this).attr('key') ]);
        });

    } );

});



// HERE'S WHERE MY BRAIN STARTS MALFUNCTIONING

if ((window.location.pathname).split('/')[1] == 'es') {
    // <-- EXECUTE FUNCTION ABOVE TO TRANSLATE TO SPANISH BASED ON PATHNAME
}

else if ((window.location.pathname).split('/')[1] == 'fr') {
    // <-- EXECUTE FUNCTION ABOVE TO TRANSLATE TO FRENCH BASED ON PATHNAME
}

else {
}
```

So it basically translates (changes the value of certain elements on the page) when clicking a button. Every time you click on it, changes to the next language. That works fine.

THE PROBLEM is, I want it 'automatically' changed to a certain language if the user is visiting from a certain link:

Example:

- www.mysite.com (nothing happens because nothing is on the pathname)
- www.mysite.com/es/ ('automatically changes values to spanish')
- www.mysite.com/fr/ ('automatically changes values to french')

---

I tried 'faking' the button click with javascript but didnt work.
Also tried 'naming' the translating function and 'call/run' it.

I know it's easier to do and I'm making it complicated but I'm such a noob.

Please, help. Or just a hint. Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: What happened when you tried calling the function?

Comment: Literally nothing.

Comment: Show us your code.  That is what you need to do.

Comment: is anything logged? this isnt a bad question... just needs some more info, we need hints too lol. One thing, maybe is that its also looking for the id to be a language code, without more info, I can assume the problem is your html doesnt have the id, since you haven shared that code..

Comment: here's the website: www.naguka.tk

Comment: it's a single page, so there's the code. I use php and include it on the 'not found page' so that I can do the .pathname thing

Answer (score 1):

Based on code above a couple thoughts:

1) lets change `aLangKeys` to an object with each key being another object.
i.e.

```
var aLangKeys={};
aLangKeys['en']={}; // Thats a named key/prop so we want an object here
...
aLangKeys['en']['language']='english'; // ditto the above comment
```

2) we probably want to move the logic that checks for locality *inside* the ready function. 
I.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // onclick behavior
    $('.language').click(function() {
       ...
    });

    // we want access to the DOM *and* maybe certain functions that do stuff. So its gotta be in here...
    if ((window.location.pathname).split('/')[1] == 'es') {
        // <-- EXECUTE FUNCTION ABOVE TO TRANSLATE TO SPANISH BASED ON PATHNAME
    }
    else if ((window.location.pathname).split('/')[1] == 'fr') {
        // <-- EXECUTE FUNCTION ABOVE TO TRANSLATE TO FRENCH BASED ON PATHNAME
    }
}); // end of ready function
```

Couple reasons:

a) we want to change the page content based on info like pathname/locality. So we want to know the page is loaded first.

b) perhaps we will want to make a function that does language processing/changing and call that from multiple places. We want that function in scope of our locality checking logic. If we define that inside the ready function scope, we will need any logic that calls that function also inside the same scope